# Java calculate hex representation of a SHA-1 digest of a String

Tags: java, hash, sha1

I'm storing the user password on the db as a sha1 hash.

Unfortunately I'm getting strange answers.

I'm storing the string as this:

```
MessageDigest cript = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
              cript.reset();
              cript.update(userPass.getBytes("utf8"));
              this.password = new String(cript.digest());
```

I wanted something like this -->

aff --> "0c05aa56405c447e6678b7f3127febde5c3a9238"

rather than

aff --> �V@\D~fx����:�8

Comment: Note: you should not be using `sha1` or like hash to hash passwords. You should use a password hash like `bcrypt` or `scrypt`.

Comment: Note: you should not be hashing passwords without salt.

Comment: Note: you should consider use char[] instead of String for password and clear it asap after using it

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is happening because cript.digest() returns a byte array, which you're trying to print out as a character String.  You want to convert it to a printable Hex String.

Easy solution: Use Apache's [commons-codec library](http://commons.apache.org/codec/):

```
String password = new String(Hex.encodeHex(cript.digest()),
                             CharSet.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Couldn't edit your post but you're trying to call the CharSet constructor without a new for a static method. I wanted to remove the () but wouldn't let me.

Comment: Getting error saying constructor String(char[],Charset) undefined. Using this this.password = Hex.encodeHexString(cript.digest());

Comment: I'm getting the same error as @thisisananth. also, the String constructor uses java.nio.charset.Charset (not CharSet)

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? String does not take char[] .

Answer (score 111):

Using apache common codec library:

```
DigestUtils.sha1Hex("aff")
```

The result is 0c05aa56405c447e6678b7f3127febde5c3a9238

That's it :)

Comment: Why doesn't it produce the same output as running the following in a terminal: `echo aff|sha1sum` --> `c4d21f9a4f09a6645eb25089d39857bc45739ef7` ?

Comment: `echo -n "aff" | sha1sum` produce the correct output (echo inserts a newline by default)

Answer (score 26):

One iteration of a hash algorithm is not secure. It's too fast. You need to perform key strengthening by iterating the hash many times.

Furthermore, you are not salting the password. This creates a vulnerability to pre-computed dictionaries, like "rainbow tables."

Instead of trying to roll your own code (or using some sketchy third-party bloatware) to do this correctly, you can use code built-in to the Java runtime. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860943/suggestions-for-library-to-hash-passwords-in-java/2861125#2861125) for details.

Once you have hashed the password correctly, you'll have a `byte[]`. An easy way to convert this to a hexadecimal `String` is with the `BigInteger` class:

```
String passwordHash = new BigInteger(1, cript.digest()).toString(16);
```

If you want to make sure that your string always has 40 characters, you may need to do some padding with zeroes on the left (you could do this with `String.format()`.)

Comment: For padding, use: `String hex = String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, cript.digest()));`

Answer (score 16):

If you don't want to add any extra dependencies to your project, you could also use

```
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
digest.update(message.getBytes("utf8"));
byte[] digestBytes = digest.digest();
String digestStr = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(digestBytes);
```

Answer (score 5):

The crypt.digest() method returns a byte[]. This byte array is the correct SHA-1 sum, but crypto hashes are typically displayed to humans in hex form.  Each byte in your hash will result in two hex digits.

To safely convert a byte to hex use this:

```
// %1$ == arg 1
// 02  == pad with 0's
// x   == convert to hex
String hex = String.format("%1$02x", byteValue);
```

[This code snippet can be used for converting a char to hex](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/examples/UnicodeFormatter.java):

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1995, 2008, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 *   - Neither the name of Oracle or the names of its
 *     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *     from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
 * IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */ 
import java.io.*;

public class UnicodeFormatter  {

   static public String byteToHex(byte b) {
      // Returns hex String representation of byte b
      char hexDigit[] = {
         '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
         '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'
      };
      char[] array = { hexDigit[(b >> 4) & 0x0f], hexDigit[b & 0x0f] };
      return new String(array);
   }

   static public String charToHex(char c) {
      // Returns hex String representation of char c
      byte hi = (byte) (c >>> 8);
      byte lo = (byte) (c & 0xff);
      return byteToHex(hi) + byteToHex(lo);
   }
}
```

Note that working with bytes in Java is very error prone.  I would double check everything and test some strange cases as well.

Also you should consider using something stronger than SHA-1.
http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/statement.html

Comment: +1 Better a tiny code snippet that can be understood (and changed, if necessary) than a multi-MB-library where you only use 1%.

Answer (score 4):

With [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava):

Maven:

```
<dependency>
   <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
   <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
   <version>14.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Sample:

```
HashCode hashCode = Hashing.sha1().newHasher()
   .putString(password, Charsets.UTF_8)
   .hash();            

String hash = BaseEncoding.base16().lowerCase().encode(hashCode.asBytes());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Spring its quite simple:

```
MessageDigestPasswordEncoder encoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder("SHA-1");
String hash = encoder.encodePassword(password, "salt goes here");
```

Answer (score 2):

There's more than just simple standard hash algorithms involved in storing passwords nonreversible.

1. Do multiple rounds to make brute-force attacks slower
2. Use a per-record "salt" as input to the hash algorithm besides the password to make dictionary attacks less feasible and avoid output collisions.
3. Use "pepper", an application-configuration-setting as input to the hash algorithm to make a stolen database-dump with an unknown "pepper" useless.
4. Pad the input to avoid weaknesses in some hash algorithms e.g. where you could append a character to the password without knowing the password, by modifying the hash.

For more info, see e.g.

- https://password-hashing.net/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Key_derivation_functions
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt

You could also use a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password-authenticated_key_agreement method to avoid passing the password in cleartext to the server at all.

Answer (score 2):

In java 17 [`HexFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HexFormat.html) is introduced.

It allows you to write:

```java
var cript = MessageDigest.getInstance("sha1");
var hexformat = HexFormat.of();
this.password = hexformat.formatHex(cript.digest(userPass.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
```

Answer (score 1):

To use UTF-8, do this:

```
userPass.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

<strike>And to get a Base64 String from the digest, you can do something like this:</strike>

```
this.password = new BASE64Encoder().encode(cript.digest());
```

Since `MessageDigest.digest()` returns a byte array, you can convert it to String using Apache's [Hex Encoding](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) (simpler).

E.g.

```
this.password = Hex.encodeHexString(cript.digest());
```

Comment: I think that he wants hex encoding

Answer (score 1):

digest() returns a byte array, which you're converting to a string using the default encoding. What you want to do is base64 encode it.

Answer (score 1):

How about converting byte[] to base64 string?

```
    byte[] chkSumBytArr = digest.digest();
    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    String base64CheckSum = encoder.encode(chkSumBytArr);
```

Comment: BASE64Encoder is not standard. It may not exist in every JVM.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code too(from crackstation.net):

```
private static String toHex(byte[] array)
{
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, array);
    String hex = bi.toString(16);
    int paddingLength = (array.length * 2) - hex.length();
    if(paddingLength > 0)
        return String.format("%0" + paddingLength + "d", 0) + hex;
    else
        return hex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        messageDigest.reset();
        messageDigest.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        String sha1String = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest.digest()).toString(16);
```

Comment: add some description too

Answer (score 1):

echo -n "aff" | sha1sum produce the correct output (echo inserts a newline by default)

Comment: echo -n str | sha1sum

Answer (score 0):

You need to hex encode the result first. `MessageDigest` returns a "raw" hash, rather than a human readable one.

Edit:

@thejh provided a link to code which should work. Personally, I'd suggest using either [Bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) or [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) to do the job. Bouncycastle would be good if you want to do any other crypto-related operations.