# Java String to SHA1

Tags: java, string, sha1

I'm trying to make a simple String to SHA1 converter in Java and this is what I've got...

```
public static String toSHA1(byte[] convertme) {
    MessageDigest md = null;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    }
    catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return new String(md.digest(convertme));
}
```

When I pass it `toSHA1("password".getBytes())`, I get `[�a�ɹ??�%l�3~��.` I know it's probably a simple encoding fix like UTF-8, but could someone tell me what I should do to get what I want which is `5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8`? Or am I doing this completely wrong?

Comment: It's good practice to specify the character encoding when you call `getBytes()`, for example use `toSHA1("password".getBytes("UTF-8"))`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java calculate a sha1 of a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400774/java-calculate-a-sha1-of-a-string)

Comment: @TheScrumMeister The standard name for this algorithm is _SHA-1_ **with hyphen**. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#MessageDigest

Answer (score 205, accepted):

**UPDATE**
You can use [Apache Commons Codec](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec) (version 1.7+) to do this job for you.

```
DigestUtils.sha1Hex(stringToConvertToSHexRepresentation)
```

Thanks to @[Jon Onstott](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895523/java-string-to-sha1/4895572?noredirect=1#comment50041639_4895572) for this suggestion.

---

**Old Answer**
Convert your Byte Array to Hex String. [Real's How To tells you how](http://rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0596.html).

```
return byteArrayToHexString(md.digest(convertme))
```

and (copied from Real's How To)

```
public static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] b) {
  String result = "";
  for (int i=0; i < b.length; i++) {
    result +=
          Integer.toString( ( b[i] & 0xff ) + 0x100, 16).substring( 1 );
  }
  return result;
}
```

---

BTW, you may get more compact representation using Base64. **Apache Commons Codec API 1.4**, has this nice utility to take away all the pain. [refer here](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64String%28byte[]%29)

Comment: base64 and sha1 are very different -- do not suggest them as alternatives.

Comment: @RyanA.: As I understand it, he suggests base64 as an alternative to hex-encoding the SHA1 hash (not as an alternative to SHA1 entirely).

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but would you care to explain how this works ?

Comment: Why not use a library like `DigestUtils.sha1Hex("my string")` instead of reinventing the wheel (though it's interesting to know how to convert to hex by hand)?

Comment: Because when this answer was written DigestUtils (1.7 was released in Sep 2012) did not have that feature. Thanks for pointing this out. +1

Comment: Do not use Apache Commons Codec. Its an unfortunately an awfully messy library.

Answer (score 74):

This is my solution of converting string to sha1. It works well in my Android app:

```
private static String encryptPassword(String password)
{
    String sha1 = "";
    try
    {
        MessageDigest crypt = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        crypt.reset();
        crypt.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        sha1 = byteToHex(crypt.digest());
    }
    catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sha1;
}

private static String byteToHex(final byte[] hash)
{
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
    for (byte b : hash)
    {
        formatter.format("%02x", b);
    }
    String result = formatter.toString();
    formatter.close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Might want to specify that this is java.util.Formatter and needs a formatter.close() at the end to avoid warning.

Comment: Shoudln't `encryptPassword("test")` and `echo test|sha1sum` in linux terminal output the same result ? They don't.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova Concerning the console invocation: If you use `echo test`, the output including a line break will be piped to `sha1sum`. If you want to hash a plain string without trailing line break, you can use `echo -n test | sha1sum`. The `-n` parameter makes `echo` omitting the line break.

Comment: Less to the question, but more in general: Your `encryptPassword()` sounds like that being used for storing authentication data.  Note that your coding is vulnerable to dictionary attacks, as no seeding is applied. Check your security environment whether this is a problem for your application!

Comment: the `byteToHex` method  tide me over

Answer (score 61):

Using [Guava Hashing class](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/Hashing.html):

```
Hashing.sha1().hashString( "password", Charsets.UTF_8 ).toString()
```

Comment: This answer might need an update since this will now produce a warning that the Hashing is unstable.

Answer (score 36):

SHA-1 (and all other hashing algorithms) return binary data. That means that (in Java) they produce a `byte[]`. That `byte` array does **not** represent any specific characters, which means you can't simply turn it into a `String` like you did.

*If* you need a `String`, then you have to format that `byte[]` in a way that can be represented as a `String` (otherwise, just keep the `byte[]` around).

Two common ways of representing arbitrary `byte[]` as printable characters are BASE64 or simple hex-Strings (i.e. representing each `byte` by two hexadecimal digits). It looks like you're trying to produce a hex-String.

There's also another pitfall: if you want to get the SHA-1 of a Java `String`, then you need to convert that `String` to a `byte[]` first (as the input of SHA-1 is a `byte[]` as well). If you simply use `myString.getBytes()` as you showed, then it will use the platform default encoding and as such will be dependent on the environment you run it in (for example it could return different data based on the language/locale setting of your OS).

A better solution is to specify the encoding to use for the `String`-to-`byte[]` conversion like this: `myString.getBytes("UTF-8")`. Choosing UTF-8 (or another encoding that can represent every Unicode character) is the safest choice here.

Answer (score 27):

This is a simple solution that can be used when converting a string to a hex format:

```
private static String encryptPassword(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    MessageDigest crypt = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    crypt.reset();
    crypt.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    return new BigInteger(1, crypt.digest()).toString(16);
}
```

Comment: Warning: Hash generation is incorrect for hashes starting with '0'. You will receive a String with 39 characters.

Comment: @philn could you suggest solution?

Comment: I guess that if you create a big integer from a byte[] with enough leading zeros, these 0s are lost. Thus, the hex string representation "0" will not be there, leading to a hash with 39 or even less chars. I used petrnohejls solution above and it works fine...

Answer (score 25):

Just use the apache commons codec library. They have a utility class called [DigestUtils](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#sha%28java.lang.String%29)

No need to get into details.

Comment: I disagree, getting into the details is sort of the whole point

Comment: The question is whether you have time to get into details or not. The whole point is usually getting it done on time.Not everyone is a student or has the luxury to learn all details.

Comment: DigestUtils returns a byte array so to get the string representation you need to run it through Hex.encodeHexString. Java: it's 2014 and we still don't have a one step sha method

Comment: One step SHA-1 method: `String result = DigestUtils.sha1Hex("An input string")` ;o)

Answer (score 19):

As mentioned before use apache commons codec. It's recommended by Spring guys as well (see DigestUtils in Spring doc). E.g.:

```
DigestUtils.sha1Hex(b);
```

Definitely wouldn't use the top rated answer here.

Answer (score 13):

It is not printing correctly because you need to use Base64 encoding. With Java 8 you can encode using [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) encoder class.

```
public static String toSHA1(byte[] convertme) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(md.digest(convertme));
}
```

**Result**

This will give you your expected output of `5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8`

Comment: @Devenv it is SHA-1 the three dots means it will maintain his original code which converts to sha1. OP's original issue was when printing the string correctly.

Comment: With Base64 encodeToString(..) I get `W6ph5Mm5Pz8GgiULbPgzG37mj9g=` instead of `5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8`

Answer (score 5):

### Message Digest (hash) is byte[] in byte[] out

A message digest is defined as a function that takes a raw byte array and returns a raw byte array (aka `byte[]`). For example [SHA-1 (Secure Hash Algorithm 1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) has a digest size of 160 bit or 20 bytes. Raw byte arrays cannot usually be interpreted as [character encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) like [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1), because not every byte in every order is a legal that encoding. So converting them to a `String` with:

```java
new String(md.digest(subject), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

might create some illegal sequences or has code-pointers to undefined [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding) mappings:

```
[�a�ɹ??�%l�3~��.
```

#### Binary-to-text Encoding

For that [binary-to-text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding) encoding is used. With hashes, the one that is used most is the [HEX encoding or Base16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Transfer_encoding). Basically a byte can have the value from `0` to `255` (or `-128` to `127` signed) which is equivalent to the HEX representation of `0x00`-`0xFF`. Therefore, hex will double the required length of the output, that means a 20 byte output will create a 40 character long hex string, e.g.:

```
2fd4e1c67a2d28fced849ee1bb76e7391b93eb12
```

Note that it is not required to use hex encoding. You could also use something like [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Hex is often preferred because it is easier readable by humans and has a defined output length without the need for padding.

You can convert a byte array to hex with JDK functionality alone:

```java
new BigInteger(1, token).toString(16)
```

Note however that `BigInteger` will interpret given byte array as *number* and not as a byte string. That means leading zeros will not be outputted, and the resulting string may be shorter than 40 chars.

#### Using Libraries to Encode to HEX

You could now [copy and paste an untested byte-to-hex method from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817752/java-code-to-convert-byte-to-hexadecimal) or use massive dependencies like [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html).

To have a go-to solution for most byte related issues I implemented a utility to handle these cases: [bytes-java (GitHub)](https://github.com/patrickfav/bytes-java)

To convert your message digest byte array you could just do

```java
String hex = Bytes.wrap(md.digest(subject)).encodeHex();
```

or you could just use the built-in hash feature

```java
String hex =  Bytes.from(subject).hashSha1().encodeHex();
```

Answer (score 3):

Base 64 Representation of `SHA1` Hash:

```
String hashedVal = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(DigestUtils.sha1(stringValue.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert byte array to hex string.

```
public static String toSHA1(byte[] convertme) {
    final char[] HEX_CHARS = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
    MessageDigest md = null;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    }
    catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] buf = md.digest(convertme);
    char[] chars = new char[2 * buf.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; ++i) {
        chars[2 * i] = HEX_CHARS[(buf[i] & 0xF0) >>> 4];
        chars[2 * i + 1] = HEX_CHARS[buf[i] & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is that when you call `String(md.digest(convertme))`, you are telling Java to interpret a sequence of encrypted bytes as a String. What you want is to convert the bytes into hexadecimal characters.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps (works on java 17):

```
import org.apache.tomcat.util.codec.binary.Base64;
return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(md.digest(convertme)));
```