# Same string but not the same at all

Tags: java, string-comparison

I'm programming both in JAVA and PHP. I got one problem with string comparison. Actually two strings that are the same (in my perspective) is not the same according to JAVA.

Background to problem:

I set a cookie using `$userid_hash = sha1($row["profileId"].'helloworld');`
along with `$userid = $row["profileId"]`. This is done to prevent a user from accessing another account.

The problem now is that I have some server code written in JAVA that is hashing the `userid` and comparing it with `userid_hash`. I print them out in the console. Both string is identical.

But the thing is I have wrapped the rest of the code around an if statement in case of any fraud attempts. And java is interpreting the strings as not the same, even though they is, according to my console in Eclipse. What can be the source of this problem?

I'm using this as my SHA1 hash [Syntax wrong with my SHA1 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158555/syntax-wrong-with-my-sha1-code). I call it using `"somestring".getBytes("UTF-8");`. And my MySQL database is UTF-8 encoded also any strings I enter in Eclipse is also UTF-8 encoded. What have I done wrong? How can I locate the problem?

**EDIT:**

This is the println statement in java before comparison:

> ab968f939a4869339b5cdb611674bdf4954f2f6a
>   ab968f939a4869339b5cdb611674bdf4954f2f6a

**EDIT:**

If statement:

```
if(packageName.toSHA1((profileId+"secret").getBytes("UTF-8")) == profileId_ver)
```

Comment: What does your if statement look like?

Are you using equalsIgnoreCase for the comparision?

Comment: You haven't shared any code, so it's very difficult to help. "I have a problem, what's the solution?" doesn't help... Are you comparing Strings properly? don't use `==`, but `.equals()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you using .equals() instead of ==? == for strings tests that they're at the same location in memory, whereas .equals() checks that they're made of the same sequence of characters (which is what you'd want here).

Good:

```
if(string1.equals(string2))
```

Bad:

```
if(string1 == string2)
```

Comment: Ok it worked now! But why can't I use `==`? I'm new to JAVA as you might see. I also wondering if there is some PHP die() function equivalent in JAVA? In case you don't know the die() function in PHP, it stops compiling after the function is called. Than I don't have to wrap braces around a big code block

Comment: == doesn't (always) work because instead of checking that the strings are made of the same sequence of characters, it checks that they're in the same location in memory (I'm not exactly sure why that is...). Sometimes this evaluates to true - if you make two identical strings, Java might just make the second one a reference to the first one, so == will be true (strings are immutable, so there's no harm in that - if one string changes, it really becomes a new string). But it does mean that you need the 'deep' checking that .equals() allows.

Comment: == is 'object sameness' it returns true if 2 references point to the same object.  equals() is logical equals -- it lets the programmer define what equals means given the objects.

Comment: Not one I would recommend using. :P

Comment: @thasc: A simple `return;` is the same as die() in PHP, at least in practice

Comment: @thasc "Because that's just how it is" (which is related to Java's lack of operator overloading, I suspect -- although, "why not just add another special-case?" ;-)

Comment: @thasc: I think your answer was so good that the other three dissapeared!