# squeryl ORM in Play with SHA1 password encryption

Tags: scala, playframework, squeryl

I am trying to insert username and encrypted password pairs into database table  using squeryl ORM framework. My code basically looks like the following:

```
      class SHA1(e: StringExpression[String], m:OutMapper[String]) extends FunctionNode[String]("sha1", Some(m), Seq(e)) with StringExpression[String]

      def sha1(e:StringExpression[String])(implicit m:OutMapper[String]) = new SHA1(e,m)
      transaction{
        val foo = TestUser.userTable insert User("test@domain.com", sha1("password"))
      }
```

But this does not work. I got an error saying:

```
type mismatch; found : controllers.SHA1 required: String Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limit to the magic that Squeryl can perform here.  Your model class takes a String value for password, and you are passing it a value of type SHA1 (the value that is returned from the sha1 function).  The scala compiler isn't going to allow that.  There are a couple of options here:

1. Hash the password before sending it to the db
2. Insert your User with a null value for the password, then update it in the same transaction with the password hashed via your function
3. If you are using Squeryl 0.9.6-SNAPSHOT, you might create a SHAString custom type that handles hashing the string when it is sent to the DB

To hash the password before you insert it, look at `java.security.MessageDigest` and see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895523/java-string-to-sha1).

Comment: Hi Dave, I am already trying to hash the password before sending it to the db. So your 1 and 2 are exactly what I am trying to do. Could you provide some additional help? Thank you.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some information on how to hash your password outside of the db before inserting the record.

Comment: You can use the _akka.util.Crypt.sha1()_ method to generate a SHA1 hash.