# Reverse engineering Javascript behind Google+ button

Tags: javascript

I am trying to simulate google+ button.In Somepart of code at [LINK](http://pastebin.com/QabqCrxk),It converts the session id into Some kinda hash.What i found is session id name is SAPISID and the converted hash name is SAPISIDHASH , Can anyone tell me which part of code does the hash part . Any help will be appreciated.i have spent 6 hours straight , still no clue :(

For Example `VUOyLIU22fNPz2ko/AbGsxW03_WHoGjaJq is SAPISID` and `f17aa630b9b9a105dad437b0fedcafe429f6fca2 is SAPISIDHASH` . In php i tried all kind of hash..nothing matches.

Comment: The hash is 40 chars of hex digits, so it's probably a [SHA-1 hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) of some data.  Exactly *what* data is anybody's guess...

Comment: Not only is it anybody's guess...  but it meant they went out of their way to make sure nobody would be able to guess it.

Comment: ripemd160 also 40 characters.. i have tried all the hash.. the code does some symbol replace i guess.. so need to find what it does

Comment: ... hunting this duck as well

Answer (score 53):

VICTORY! Well for me at least . The `SAPISIDHASH` I was looking for was the
one in the API console. Automation for rather large job, totally legitimate.
The one I found was a SHA1 on the current JavaScript milliseconds timestamp
plus your current `SAPISID` from your cookie plus the domain origin. In order
for my request to work I had to include the following headers in the request:

```
Authorization:SAPISIDHASH 1439879298823_<hidden sha1 hash value>
```

and:

```
X-Origin:https://console.developers.google.com
```

The first header I assume tells the server your timestamp and your SHA1 value.
The second (breaks if you don't include it) tells it the origin to use in the
SHA1 algorithm. I found the algorithm by digging through and debugging the hell
out of tons of minified JS **NOTE there are spaces appended between the
values**. The psuedo code is basically:

```
sha1(new Date().getTime() + ' ' + SAPISID + ' ' + origin);
```

That is at least how I got my `SAPISIDHASH` value in my use case here in 2015
(few years later I know)... different from yours but maybe I will help some
other young good hacker out there one day.

Comment: If you want to laugh, new Creator Manager seems to use also SAPISIDHASH : Another challenge if you want ^^

Comment: Thanks, you're the best. I got the same resolution with a differente API

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dave. You save my time :)

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! Python: `sha1(' '.join([str(int(time.time())), cookie['SAPISID'].coded_value, 'https://subdomain.google.com']).encode()).hexdigest()`

Comment: How do people figure out stuff like that? Lol

Answer (score 8):

All credits to Dave Thomas.

I just want to clarify that for the X-Origin, or Origin, you do not include the "X-Origin:" or "Origin:"

Here is one example :

```java
public class SAPISIDHASH {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        String sapisid = "b4qUZKO4943exo9W/AmP2OAZLWGDwTsuh1";
        String origin = "https://hangouts.google.com";
        String sapisidhash = "1447033700279" + " " + sapisid + " " + origin;
        System.out.println("SAPISID:\n"+ hashString(sapisidhash));
        System.out.println("Expecting:");
        System.out.println("38cb670a2eaa2aca37edf07293150865121275cd");

    }

    private static String hashString(String password)
    {
        String sha1 = "";
        try
        {
            MessageDigest crypt = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            crypt.reset();
            crypt.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            sha1 = byteToHex(crypt.digest());
        }
        catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sha1;
    }

    private static String byteToHex(final byte[] hash)
    {
        Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
        for (byte b : hash)
        {
            formatter.format("%02x", b);
        }
        String result = formatter.toString();
        formatter.close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

source for sha1 in Java :
[Java String to SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895523/java-string-to-sha1#answer-9071224)

Answer (score 0):

This works in 2024 for youtube (js with Deno runtime)

```
const now = new Date();
const origin = "https://studio.youtube.com";
const timems = now.getTime() + (now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000)
const timesec = Math.round(timems / 1000);
const SAPISID = cookieArray['SAPISID']; // you should know how to get it
const newHash = timesec + '_' + sha1(timesec + ' ' + SAPISID + ' ' + origin, "utf8", "hex"); // this sha1 function is from deno package but you can use any other from the samples above
SAPISIDHASH = newHash; // 1704658177_78eb913fea82472cd726b118c51a6071f9d794f3
```

I use sha1 from deno but you can use any other realization for sha1 from samples above.