# set a video's game using youtube data api

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am looking for a way to programatically set a video's game. By "game" I mean the video setting that makes these things appear in the video's description:

[image]

I can set and read the category using the `categoryId` field, e.g. `"20"` for Gaming. But I was unable to find any official way to set some kind of game id.

The Youtube Studio seems to perform this action to achieve the goal (shortened):

```
POST https://studio.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/video_manager/metadata_update
{
  "encryptedVideoId": "UEUN1xD6BFI",
  "videoReadMask": {...},
  "gameTitle": {
    "newKgEntityId": "/g/11gfhqhs78"
  },
  "context": {...}
}
```

And it uses something called `SAPISIDHASH` for authorization, which some people [seem to have reverse-engineered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32065323/3688648), but before I even try to do that I wanted to see if there's an official supported way of doing this.

Comment: Ah, the exact question I was going to post has already been posted and has a bounty: excellent! It has a negative answer: not excellent...

Comment: Felk, consider post your requirement also in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues).

Comment: I did, thanks for the link

Comment: Here's the link to the issue I raised: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136362569

Comment: I am trying to do this put seem to keep getting an error i have the SAPISIDHASH right as i can check it against working ones from the browser and I get the same one.  My guess is my issue is in the Dictonary that i am sending but i cant figure it out. 
                domain = "gdata.CoreErrorDomain";
                location = client;
                locationType = other;
                message = "Unknown error.";
                reason = "INVALID_VALUE";
            }
        );
        message = "Unknown error.";
        status = "INVALID_ARGUMENT";
    };
}

Answer (score 3):

No ! There is not any supported way to do this as I know, an old friend of mine used the `SAPISIDHASH`method, and that was working like a charm, maybe a day they will open this for everyone