# Enable sign-in methods in firebase project from API or gcloud

Tags: typescript, firebase, api, automation, gcloud

Its possible to enable sign-in methods (like email and password, for example) in a firebase project with no use the console interface? I tried use a PATCH request to [https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/admin/v2/projects/{project-id}/config?updateMask=signIn.email.enabled,signIn.email.passwordRequired](https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/admin/v2/projects/%7Bproject-id%7D/config?updateMask=signIn.email.enabled,signIn.email.passwordRequired), without success. Is it possible to be made with gcloud cli or API request?

Answer (score 1):

A general-purpose mechanism for answering this type of question is to use a combination of:

1. Chrome's Developer Tools to monitor network calls while you make changes in the Console;
2. Google's [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) to interpret REST calls.

I was intrigued by your question and tried this on my own project.

By adding, enabling and then deleting the Email provider in the Firebase Console, I was able to grab the underlying REST API calls against `identitytoolkit.googleapis.com`.

E.g. Adding uses [projects.updateConfig](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/updateConfig):

`/admin/v2/projects/${PROJECT}/config?updateMask=signIn.email.enabled,signIn.email.passwordRequired&alt=json&key=${API_KEY}`

And a request body:

```
{
  "signIn": {
    "email": {
      "enabled": true,
      "passwordRequired": true
    }
  }
}
```

There are various request headers you may want to check, including:

```
authorization: SAPISIDHASH {VALUE}
```

I've not seen `SAPISIDHASH` before but others have, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32065323/609290) answer.

So, you'll need to try to repro `PATCH`ing the API using that `updateMask`, your own API key, the body ([`Config`](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/Config)) and some variant of those request headers.