# Authenticate from chrome extension to Google Cloud API without Client ID?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-chrome-extension

Google Cloud Console contains a number of pages where project number (in the form of 123456789012) is shown. Project numbers (123456789012) aren't very human readable, so I wanted to build a chrome extension that would create tooltips over strings containing the project number where the tooltip text would be the project name.

I wanted to implement a mechanism where the chrome extension pulls the project numbers/project names from Google API. I need to authenticate to the Google API, so I implemented auth with approach similar to [this](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/how-to/integrate/oauth).  Only difference is that I used [launchWebAuthFlow](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow) so that it would work in Microsoft Edge as well.

This approach requires that I set up a client ID and use OAuth.  I want to share this chrome extension with others so that they can use it in their Google Cloud Console and get the advantage of having the tooltip when they browse to various pages. However, the use of client id / oauth means if I want to share this chrome extension with others, I will have to:

- Option 1: Keep the client configured in my Google Cloud Project's API Credentials configuration and publish my OAuth Consent screen / App.  This isn't really I want to do. Any logins will go towards token grant rate limit. And this was just a temporary setup I created for testing. Also, the users will have to accept and trust my application.
- Option 2: Anybody that wants to use it would have to set up their own application / client ID in their google cloud environment. And then update the extension manifest with the correct client ID.  This is too much friction.

Since users are logged in already to the google cloud console, I would think there should be a way to use the cookies already available in the browser.  I looked into this, but couldn't find any documentation about how to do something like this. Reverse engineering it also seemed a little problematic (Inspecting the traffic, there are numerous cookies involved and authentication / authorization uses `Authorization:SAPISIDHASH`. The only relevant info on this is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907352/reverse-engineering-javascript-behind-google-button) from 10+ years ago)

Are there other alternatives to pull the project numbers/project names? Perhaps using cookies already present in the browser? Or some other method that doesn't require configuring and maintaining an OAuth client id?

Comment: AFAIK you will not be able to hook into Google's authentication/authorization cookies - however, I might be wrong. I would use a service account for authorization. Write a document that shows the user/customer how to create the service account in their Google Cloud project and the required IAM roles. I do not know how to write Chrome extensions, but your plugin should be able to use the service account to make the required API requests.

Comment: @JohnHanley Yea service account might be a good approach. I'll look into that and give it a shot. Thanks for the suggestion.