# How to create a license value that belongs to one user SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing

I have a java swing application that interacts with MySQL and i want to be able to create license key that allow the user to use the application, the user can only have one license number, here is what i have so far in SQL.

```sql
CREATE TABLE User (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    License VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Address (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    LicenseNumber VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (LicenseNumber) REFERENCES User(id),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
 );
```

Is this the correct solution? also what would be a good way to generate the actual License Number with SQL?

This is my solution to my question: 
Here is the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE User(
   id int NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
   LicenseID VARCHAR(100) NULL,
   CONSTRAINT fk_license_number FOREIGN KEY (LicenseID) REFERENCES License(LicenseNumber)
 );

CREATE TABLE License(
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
   LicenseNumber VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

For the LicenseNumber, i went ahead and used sha1 in my java code 
[Java String to SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895523/java-string-to-sha1)

Comment: No. If `Address.LicenseNumber` is a reference to `User.id`, it should have the same type (`INT`), and be called something like `user_id`. Not `LicenseNumber`. And SQL is used to query the database. Not to generate license numbers.

Comment: Can you elaborate what purpose did you have in mind for `Address` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rather use license id as a Foreign Key rather than a license number. Therefore schema should rather look like

```sql
CREATE TABLE License
(
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  LicenseNumber VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE User
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  LicenseID INT, 
  CONSTRAINT fk_license_number FOREIGN KEY (LicenseID) REFERENCES License(id)
);
```

If you need to you can generate SHA1 on db-side by using [`SHA1()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1) function. E.g.:

```sql
INSERT INTO License (LicenseNumber) VALUES (SHA1('Lisence1'));
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72abfb/1)** demo

Comment: @Rick You're quite welcome. If you feel like the answer was helpful please, consider to mark it as accepted. **[Here is how you can do it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)**.