# I need to encrypt the password from client side using java gwt but import java.security is not available

Tags: java, encryption, gwt, java.security

when i try to compile in java gwt its displaying the issues below

1. The import java.security cannot be resolved
2. MessageDigest cannot be resolved to a type
3. NoSuchAlgorithmException cannot be resolved to a type

note: versions used
gwt 2.0
java 6 (jre 1.6) tried in 1.8 as well

```
public static String EncryptPassowrd(String password)
    {
        String encryptedPassword = "";
        byte[] actualBytes = password.toString().getBytes();
        byte[] newbytes = new byte[actualBytes.length * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < actualBytes.length; i++)
        {
            newbytes[2 * i] = actualBytes[i];
            newbytes[2 * i + 1] = 0;
        }
        try
        {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            md.reset();
            md.update(newbytes);
            byte[] encryptedbytes = md.digest();
            for (int i = 0; i < encryptedbytes.length; i++)
            {
                encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword == "" ? Integer.toString((encryptedbytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1) : encryptedPassword + "-"
                    + Integer.toString((encryptedbytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
            }
            return encryptedPassword.toUpperCase();
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            // Do Nothing
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: updated the Question with code please go through it@FabioAssuncao

Comment: This looks like what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895523/java-string-to-sha1

Answer (score 5):

java.security is not included in the subset of the Java runtime library that GWT emulates, as it was already mentioned.

Although you could use GWT-Crypto to go around it, password encryption is not secure, especially on the client side - check [GWT-Crypto own wiki](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gwt-crypto/wikis/ClientSideEncryptionConsiderations.wiki). Instead, the plain text password should be sent over an encrypted channel (SSL) and processed securely on the server (for example, hashed with bcrypt). Since hash functions are one-way function, you won't be able to "decrypt" the hashes. In order to authenticate your user, you can run the password through the hash function again in order to compare with the hash that is stored in the database.

Answer (score 1):

The package `java.security` is not part of [GWT's standard library emulation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html).

So you cannot use such classes in GWT client side code. Use special GWT encryption libraries like [gwt-crypto](https://github.com/wokier/gwt-crypto) instead.