# Encoding in java (js to java)

Tags: java, javascript, android, cryptography, sha1

I've got this piece of js code which I need to convert to proper java code for usage in my Android app:

```
toHex(Crypto.util.bytesToBase64(Crypto.SHA1(password, { asBytes: true })));
```

I've found out that for the `Crypto.util.bytesToBase64()` method, I can use the java version: `Base64.encode()`, but I've got no clue how to call the js `CryptoSHA1()` and `toHex()` methods in java. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you *really* need the `toHex` part? By the time you've converted it to base64, it's ASCII text anyway... as for the `SHA1` part, a search for SHA1 and Java should get you lots of hits...

Comment: @JonSkeet Well this is what the js code looks like. This output is posted to a server, so I bet the `toHex` is needed. Not 100% sure though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400774/java-calculate-a-sha1-of-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code uses three functions:

1. SHA-1 digest

   MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
   byte[] digest = md.digest(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
2. Base 64

   String base64 = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(digest)
3. Hex

Use a function like this: http://vinnysoft.blogspot.de/2010/11/code-snippet-to-convert-string-to-hex.html

In summary the last step is totally unnecessary and only blows up the data. The result of base64 is already a printable ASCII String.

Furthermore hashing a password using SHA-1 can be insecure depending what you do with the result. Usually password hashing should always incorporate salting.