# Java SHA1 output not the same as Linux's sha1sum command

Tags: java, linux, sha1

I've tried the following code to produce a SHA1 digest of a String:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Formatter;

public class SHA1 {
    private static String encryptPassword(String password)
    {
        String sha1 = "";
        try
        {
            MessageDigest crypt = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            crypt.reset();
            crypt.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            sha1 = byteToHex(crypt.digest());
        }
        catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sha1;
    }

    private static String byteToHex(final byte[] hash)
    {
        Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
        for (byte b : hash)
        {
            formatter.format("%02x", b);
        }
        String result = formatter.toString();
        formatter.close();
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(SHA1.encryptPassword("test"));

    }
}
```

This code was based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895523/java-string-to-sha1) and [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400774/java-calculate-a-sha1-of-a-string). Note that this is not a duplicate of those questions since they are about formatting the output.

The problem is that it produces a different result than running the same input string through `sha1sum` command in Linux -> `echo test|sha1sum`.

Java code output for "test" -> `a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3`
sha1sum in linux terminal for "test" -> `4e1243bd22c66e76c2ba9eddc1f91394e57f9f83`

- Why aren't they the same ?
- Don't Java's `MessageDigest` class and Linux's `sha1sum` utility implement the same algorithm ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is how you're using `sha1sum` under Linux with echo. It's including the line feed. To split it into steps:

```
echo test > somefile
sha1sum somefile
```

will show you the same result... but if you look at `somefile` you'll see it's *5* bytes long instead of 4. Edit it to get rid of the trailing line feed, run `sha1sum` again and you'll see the same answer that Java gives.

If you use the `-n` option for `echo`, it should be fine:

```
$ echo -n test | sha1sum
a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3  -
```

Comment: Do you get a secret hat for responding within 5 minutes? Good one :-)

Comment: I had the same problem with `sha1sum` myself, unrelated to Java; my problem was with PHP. I was thankful to find you answer.