# How can I retrieve two fields of a table in Mysql with Java?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have a `ClientsTable` like that :

```
firstName lastName address idNumber userName password
         |        |       |        |        |
david      bowie    here    123     mick      jagger 
chuck      norris   there   456     steven    seagal
```

I want to get both the `userName` and the `password` of each row and verify it with the given parameters of my method :

```
public Person verifyClientExists(String username,String password) throws SQLException
{

    ResultSet results = this.m_statement.executeQuery("SELECT `userName` FROM `ClientsTable`");  
    while (results.next() == true)
    {
        // here I want to compare the retrieved data from 
                    // mysql with the "username" and "password" given in the prototype
    }



    return null;

}
```

But with my current query I can only get **one** field .

How can I retrieve two fields?

Comment: It's a bad practice to store the password in plaintext in the database.

Comment: @MarkByers: Okay , so what should do instead ? encryption ?

Comment: Use something like PBKDF2 or bcrypt. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860943/suggestions-for-library-to-hash-passwords-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use

```
select username, password from clientstable
```

? And then your `ResultSet` interrogation is:

```
String username = results.getString("username");
String password = results.getString("password");
```

See [the JDBC tutorial page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) on `ResultSets`. Note that I ask for the results by column name. It's fractionally more robust than by asking for them by index (number). If I change the SQL statement (reorder query parameters) then the correct columns are still returned.

I hope you're not storing cleartext passwords in those tables, btw! See [here](http://throwingfire.com/storing-passwords-securely/) for more info on hashing and salts.

Comment: Good answer +1 & chosen , for the mentioning the importance of password encryption .

Answer (score 2):

Change your query to:

```
SELECT `userName`, `password` FROM `ClientsTable`
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I would suggest using the APIs to build queries, and not execute raw queries (take a look [here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/IDS00-J.+Sanitize+untrusted+data+passed+across+a+trust+boundary)).

But to answer your question - if you want to get also the password use:

```
ResultSet results = this.m_statement.executeQuery("SELECT `userName`, `password` FROM `ClientsTable`");
```

Answer (score 1):

alternatively, you can check the number of records from the result:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM   `ClientsTable`
WHERE  userName = 'userHere' AND
       password = 'passHere'
```

the result here would be 0 and 1 only :) because I assume that the `username` is unique.

but if you want to retrieve the `username` and the `password`, just select the two columns in your query.

```
SELECT `userName`, `password` 
FROM `ClientsTable`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ask for more fields like this: `SELECT userName, password FROM ClientsTable`

Then use `resultSet.getString(1)` for `userName` and `resultSet.getString(2)` for `password`

Answer (score 1):

Change your sql to "SELECT `userName` ,`password` FROM `ClientsTable`

Now you can use the resultset object and fetch the values
results.getString(1)
results.getString(2)

or you can retrieve using the fieldName
results.getString("userName");
results.getString("password");

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong. Your query should be like  :-

```
SELECT EMP_NAME,EMP_PASSWORD FROM EMP_DETAILS TABLE;
```

Its quite simple to retrieve not only 2 field but also any number of field.