# How do I compare two passwords (create password and confirm password) useing the .equals() method?

Tags: java, swing, serialization, passwords

I'm building a simple create account user GUI that is integrated with my LogInScreen class. It creates a simple User, serializes it, and then lets me use that access in my log in program. The problem is, when I type in my passwords, they're never correct. I always get a problem where my program tells me that my passwords are not the same. I'm not sure how to fix this, and I would like to know how. I'll post my code below(the whole thing, along with my serializing class because the problem may be here).

User Class:

```
package passwordProgram;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class User implements Serializable, ActionListener {

    public static ArrayList<String> allUsernames = new ArrayList<String>();

    String username;
    String password;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        User user = new User();
        user.mainGUI();
    }



    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JTextField createUsername;
    JPasswordField createPassword;
    JPasswordField confirmPassword;
    JButton createAccount;
    JLabel noValid;

    public void mainGUI() {
        noValid = new JLabel();
        frame = new JFrame("Create a new account!");
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        createPassword = new JPasswordField(10);
        confirmPassword = new JPasswordField(10);
        createUsername = new JTextField(10);
        JLabel userTxt = new JLabel("New Username: ");
        JLabel userPass = new JLabel("New Password: ");
        JLabel confirmPass = new JLabel("Confirm Password: ");
        createAccount = new JButton("Create your account!");

        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints left = new GridBagConstraints();
        left.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        GridBagConstraints right = new GridBagConstraints();
        right.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        right.weightx = 2.0;
        right.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        right.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, noValid);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
        panel.add(userTxt, left);
        panel.add(createUsername, right);
        panel.add(userPass, left);
        panel.add(createPassword, right);
        panel.add(confirmPass, left);
        panel.add(confirmPassword, right);

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, createAccount);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 300);

        createAccount.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (createUsername.getText().length() <= 0 ) {
            noValid.setText("That is not a valid username. Please try again.");
            frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, noValid);
        }

        else if (allUsernames.contains(createUsername.getText())) {
            noValid.setText("That username is already taken. Please try again.");
            frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, noValid);
        }

            //THIS IS THE PART I'M CONFUSED ABOUT
        else if (!(createPassword.getPassword().equals(confirmPassword.getPassword()))) {
            noValid.setText("Your passwords do not match!");
            frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, noValid);
        } else {    
            SaveUser sUser = new SaveUser();
            sUser.createAccount(this);
            noValid.setText("Account created successfully");
            frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, noValid);
        }
    }
}
```

And the serializing class:

```
package passwordProgram;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class SaveUser {
    public void createAccount(User u) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOS = new FileOutputStream("userInfo.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream objectOS = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOS);
            objectOS.writeObject(u);
            objectOS.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing, you should never couple a class and it's GUI. The GUI and classes should all have separate files, cause what if you wanted to use `User` again somewhere with a different GUI, or without a GUI?

Comment: The `serializable` class does not declare a `static final serialversionuid` field of type `long`

Comment: Not related to the question, though do use `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)` for graciously closing your Swing Application. Moreover if you working on `JDK 7`, then stop using `frame.getContentPane().add(blahblah)`, instead simply use `frame.add(blahblah, BorderLayout.CENTER)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getPassword()` returns `char[]`, not `String`. Use

```
!(Arrays.equals(createPassword.getPassword(), confirmPassword.getPassword()))
```

instead

Answer (score 5):

Unless this is a toy project, you shouldn't store the passwords in plaintext.  Instead, store a hash of the password; when the user logs in, hash the password and compare it to the stored hash.  [This question's accepted answer has some sample hashing code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860943/suggestions-for-library-to-hash-passwords-in-java).

Comment: +1 for a good point, but this doesn't actually answer the question.  The question is actually about comparing two char[] variables for equality.

Comment: Guilty as charged, but by the time I posted four other people had already answered the question.

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot Thanks for the answer, even though it was kind of irrelevant. If you want to look at my full code and answer my other question, you can go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116168/how-do-i-solve-this-serialization-error-on-my-log-in-create-account-program)

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing `char` array `Objects` (returned by [getPassword()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword%28%29)) rather than than contents of the arrays themselves. The safest way to compare these 2 arrays is by using `Arrays#equals`:

```
else if (!(Arrays.equals(createPassword.getPassword(), 
                            confirmPassword.getPassword()))) {
```

Answer (score 3):

`JPasswordField.getPassword()` returns a `char[]`.  Calling `array1.equals(array2)` with two char arrays (like you are doing) will check if they are the same object reference, not if they have the same contents.  You want to use [`Array.equals(char[] array1, char[] array2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html), like so:

```
else if (!Array.equals(createPassword.getPassword(), confirmPassword.getPassword()))
```

Answer (score 2):

`getPassword()` returns a `char[]`. So instead try:

```
if (!(new String(createPassword.getPassword()).equals(new String(confirmPassword.getPassword()))
```

Comment: You should avoid converting the password char array to String, this exposes the password to potential hacks as the String becomes internalized to the JVM (sure, it might not be a enterprise application, but would encourage good practices where ever possible)