# How to add a password to a prepared statement in java

Tags: java, sql, passwords, jpasswordfield

Can any one help with this issue that I'm having using prepared statements. The problem comes when trying to add the password to the statement which I am taking from a JPasswordField.

```
String Query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?";

PreparedStatement PrepedStatement = Con.prepareStatement(Query);

PrepedStatement.setString(1, Username.getText());
PrepedStatement.setString(2, Password.getPassword());
//It is no having any of this as getPassword() returns a Char[] which isn't a string
```

So does anyone have any ideas. Cheers.

Comment: I **hope** you aren't storing the passwords in plain text in your database.

Comment: Well I am atm but I should probably be SALTing them shouldn't I.

Comment: SALTing the password on input to a one-way cryptographic hash.

Comment: You wouldn't have a link to that would you. It would be much appreciated.

Comment: This SO post has a pretty good reference for what you will need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142745/how-do-i-generate-a-salt-in-java-for-salted-hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will likely work, however, I strongly consider noting Elliott Frisch's comment.

String has an overloaded constructor can take a character array as a parameter.

> PrepedStatement.setString(2, new String(Password.getPassword()));

Comment: Thanks but I am probably just going to do it Elliott Frisch's approach.

Comment: A very dangerous recommendation.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Why?

Comment: Because you're telling to store a non-disguised password String in a database, something you should **never** recommend as the password now becomes easily discoverable. Please see the links in the comments to his original question.

Comment: I understand that.  But that's not what I meant by answering this question this way.  That's why I asked him to take a look at the comments.  I apologize if that is how it came across.

Comment: _Because you're telling to store a non-disguised password String in a database_ - this is other issue, question was in another...