# Password saving in DB

Tags: java, swing, hibernate

I'm not familiar with password saving AT ALL. I have a javaApp with user-password features for a school project. It's connected to a Oracle DB and I don't want to store the passwords in String format. It's very ugly.

Any simple way to store the passwords in just a bit more adequate (secure) way?

If I store the passwords in a char[] format will there be any difference?

Comment: Short answer is, don't.  You should never try and maintain the "actual" password if you have can, it's to great a security risk, instead, create a one way has of the password and store that instead

Comment: You need to "salt" (append a random string) and hash the password. ***Never*** store the password itself. Only store the salt and the hashed-and-salted version of the password. This is a huge topic. I'd suggest you start reading the OWASP materials on this. Most importantly, use an existing library and do not try to "roll your own."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The go-to package for Java 8 password hashing is MessageDigest. You'll want to hash the user input password and compare it to some stored hashed password in your DB.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html

Answer (score 2):

Additional to the answer, I suggest to use salted hash passwords rather just hashed passwords. OWASP site provides good source of information about how to prevent hacking and all. Please refer this link https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Hashing_Java https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm is a well explained blob. This blob explians what you should do and  not. How to generate salted and hashed password in java is explained by this link too. [How do I generate a SALT in Java for Salted-Hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142745/how-do-i-generate-a-salt-in-java-for-salted-hash).

Answer (score 0):

Always store your password in hashes. Look for hash functions like SHA (Secure Hash Algorithm).
You should:

1. Storing: convert the password to hash and store the hash in db
2. Authenticating: Convert the password in hash and compare with the hash stored in db

Answer (score 0):

Try this at Oracle database end.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm#BJFGFDFG][1]