# Symfony FOSUser Hash algorithm in java

Tags: java, php, hash, symfony-3.1

hey everyone am trying to find out which algorithm of hash is used my `symfony FOS User Bundle` I've done some research , and it's mentioned that `FOSUser Bundle` default security config uses `Sha512()` and itirate it over `5000` times + salt then bas64 encoding i'm actually new with these `hash` algorithms ,however this is the algorithm in `php`

```
$password = 'toto';
$salt = '1234';
$salted = $password.'{'.$salt.'}';
$digest = hash('sha512', $salted, true);

for ($i=1; $i<5000; $i++) {
  $digest = hash('sha512', $digest.$salted, true);
}

$encodedPassword = base64_encode($digest); 
}
```

taking from this post [How do I generate a SALT in Java for Salted-Hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142745/how-do-i-generate-a-salt-in-java-for-salted-hash)

since am not familiar with `java` `hash` `libraries` can anyone help me how to translated  this code into `Java` !

Comment: could you be more clear , do you need this for login ?

Comment: thanks for answering actually i want to login  from java app

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Symfony default setting for password encryption is `Bcrypt` this code mentioned in your `security.yml` config file

```
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost:      15
```

in my case i used a trick since all my password start with 13 am assuming that the `salt` equals to `13` 
so i tried translating it into java by using the java `BCrypt` library

```
public boolean checkPassword(String passwordText, String DbHash) {
    boolean password_verified = false;
    if (null == DbHash || !DbHash.startsWith("$2a$")) {
        throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException("Invalid hash provided for comparison");
    }
    password_verified = BCrypt.checkpw(passwordText, DbHash);
    return (password_verified);
 }
```

`passwordText` you actual password  , `DbHash` stored hash

This code check a password hash if password match or not

**there's a trick symfony hashed password start with `$2y$` so to make this work you need to need change `$2y$` to `$2a$`**

for exemple i have password with a hash value that is stored in my database

```
String passwordText = "admin"; 
String DbHash  = "$2y$13$VVmaKXzaS2QWgU1S4I8h5eJgC/DduF2fXmnhvcynro004GCUAQfr2";
```

change this :

```
String DbHash  = "$2y$13$VVmaKXzaS2QWgU1S4I8h5eJgC/DduF2fXmnhvcynro004GCUAQfr2";
```

to this :

```
String DbHash  = "$2a$13$VVmaKXzaS2QWgU1S4I8h5eJgC/DduF2fXmnhvcynro004GCUAQfr2";
```

Comment: Thank you so all i need to add is to change the 3rd char with `a`

Comment: the question is about the sha512 algorithm and not bcrypt

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use a Java API that encode the password like the [MessageDigestPasswordEncoder](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.php):

1. Generate a salt (lenght=43):

   ```
   private static String generateSalt() {
   SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
   byte[] salt = new byte[SALT_SIZE];
   random.nextBytes(salt);
   String saltBase64_encoded=BaseEncoding.base64().encode(salt);
   String saltPlusDot= saltBase64_encoded.replace("+",".");
   return saltPlusDot.substring(0,saltPlusDot.length()-1);
   ```

   }

BaseEncoding.base64() is a class in [commons-codec api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.7)

2. concat: password + { + salt + }:

   ```
   private static String mergePasswordAndSalt(String pass, String salt) {
   if (salt == null) {
       return salt;
   }
   String cg="{";String cd="}";
   return pass+cg+salt+cd;
   ```

   }
3. For each additional iteration: hash the concat of previous digest + 
   salt:

**private static byte[] encodePassword(String password,String salt) 
throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,UnsupportedEncodingException {**

```
    String mergedPasswordAndSalt =mergePasswordAndSalt(password, salt);  
    MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance(ALGORITHM);

    byte[] hash = digester.digest(mergedPasswordAndSalt .getBytes("UTF-8"));

    for (int i = 1; i < ITERATIONS; ++i) {


     hash = digester.digest(Bytes.concat(hash, mergedPasswordAndSalt.getBytes("UTF-8")));   

    }
        return hash;
    }
```

Bytes.concat(bytes ...)  is a method in [guava 19.0 api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/19.0)

This is the  API in github [FOSJcrypt](https://github.com/zain17/FOSJCryptAPI)