# Getting different hash values of the same password (+ salt)

Tags: java, javafx, hash, salt

I was trying to get a hashed password following the code in [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142745/how-do-i-generate-a-salt-in-java-for-salted-hash) From it, i'm only using, at the moment, the code for the `salt` method, the `hash` method and `isExpectedPassword` method.

I get my password from a text field:

```
char[] passCharArray = txtPassword.toString().toCharArray();
```

Then I call the class to get a salt value (I call it `Encryptor` instead of `Passwords` like in the original post):

```
byte[] salt = Encryptor.getNextSalt();
```

And then I get the hashed password:

```
byte[] hashedPass = Encryptor.hash(passCharArray, salt);
```

Using the following code I print the results to see what's going on and the results are commented:

```
String saltString = Arrays.toString(salt);
System.out.println("SALT: " + saltString);
//SALT: [18, 117, -98, 41, 92, 124, 118, 17, 107, 14, 0, -81, 110, 70, 10, 42]

String hashedPassString = Arrays.toString(hashedPass);
System.out.println("HASHED PASS: " + hashedPassString);
//HASHED PASS: [44, -127, -43, 84, 40, -16, -46, -71, 109, -44, -41, 47, -61, -119, 21, 99, -23, 101, -13, 116, -12, 118, -66, 44, 104, 5, 4, 18, -55, 47, 59, 116]

System.out.println("Passwords match: " + Encryptor.isExpectedPassword(passCharArray, salt, hashedPass));
//Passwords match: false
```

The below two are the `System.out.print`s I put in the `isExpectedPassword` method to see what values that one has upon being called.

```
//Encryptor pwdHash: [-103, -87, 53, -75, 59, 11, 77, 116, 123, 59, 68, -35, 16, -68, 42, 34, -32, 75, 22, -94, -37, -26, 16, 20, 7, -46, -6, -20, -88, 104, -121, 77]
//Encryptor expectedHash: [44, -127, -43, 84, 40, -16, -46, -71, 109, -44, -41, 47, -61, -119, 21, 99, -23, 101, -13, 116, -12, 118, -66, 44, 104, 5, 4, 18, -55, 47, 59, 116]
```

So basically, `hashedPass` (and `expectedHash`) should be the same as `pwdHash`, but it's not. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Am I missing something in my code? Does something change without my knowledge?

This is my full code, if people want to see the whole thing just in case:

```
public class Encryptor {

    private static final Random RANDOM = new SecureRandom();
    private static final int ITERATIONS = 10000;
    private static final int KEY_LENGTH = 256;

    private Encryptor(){}

    public static byte[] getNextSalt(){
        byte[] salt = new byte[16];
        RANDOM.nextBytes(salt);
        return salt;
    }

    public static byte[] hash(char[] password, byte[] salt) {
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, ITERATIONS, KEY_LENGTH);
        Arrays.fill(password, Character.MIN_VALUE);
        try {
            SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            return skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new AssertionError("Error while hashing a password: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            spec.clearPassword();
        }
    }

    public static boolean isExpectedPassword(char[] password, byte[] salt, byte[] expectedHash) {
        byte[] pwdHash = hash(password, salt);

        String s = Arrays.toString(pwdHash);
        System.out.println("Encryptor pwdHash: " + s);

        String s2 = Arrays.toString(expectedHash);
        System.out.println("Encryptor expectedHash: " + s2);

        Arrays.fill(password, Character.MIN_VALUE);
        if (pwdHash.length != expectedHash.length) return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < pwdHash.length; i++) {
            if (pwdHash[i] != expectedHash[i]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


}


public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Button btnLogin;
    //Some private variables

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane ancPane;
    @FXML
    private ImageView imgLogo;
    @FXML
    private Hyperlink hplRegister;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtUsername;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtPassword;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        //Some styling

        hplRegister.setOnAction(event -> {
            //Registering event
        });

        btnLogin.setOnAction(event -> {
            try {

                //Loading fxml data
                // I've put the code here just for testing purposes
                // and will not be the final placement.

                char[] passCharArray = txtPassword.toString().toCharArray();

                byte[] salt = Encryptor.getNextSalt();
                byte[] hashedPass = Encryptor.hash(passCharArray, salt);

                String saltString = Arrays.toString(salt);
                System.out.println("SALT: " + saltString);

                String hashedPassString = Arrays.toString(hashedPass);
                System.out.println("HASHED PASS: " + hashedPassString);

                System.out.println("Passwords match: " + Encryptor.isExpectedPassword(passCharArray, salt, hashedPass));

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    //Some getter methods.
}
```

Comment: Your salt isn't the same. `getNextSalt()` will randomly create a salt each call. This will cause your hash to be different every time

Comment: Furthermore `TextField.toString` does not return the content of the `TextField`. The result is something like `TextField@5ef8216b[styleClass=text-input text-field]` or `PasswordField@67d95601[styleClass=text-input text-field password-field]` for `PasswordField`. You need to use `getText()` instead.

Comment: @locus2k That's why I store it in `byte[] salt`, so I don't have to call it again. I'm using the same variable in `byte[] hashedPass` and `Encryptor.isExpectedPassword(passCharArray, salt, hashedPass)`.

Comment: the problem is not `getNextSalt()` or the field. @fabian is right that the text you're getting is not the text you want, but the hash and match should still work. see below for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are wiping out password. when you hash the password you wipe out the char array fill it with blanks this clears `passCharArray`. When you pass it the second time it's basically checking the hash of the password versus the hash of a blank array. and those definitely do not match.

In a real case you will get salt and hashed password from a db or some other source. The incoming version will not be hashed, and thus cleared, until passed to `isExpectedPassword`

Comment: After fixing `txtPassword.toString().toCharArray();` to `txtPassword.getText().toCharArray();` and commenting off the `Arrays.fill(password, Character.MIN_VALUE);`, it seems to work properly. I don't even know why it's there in the first place.

Comment: it's there because it doesn't want those values just floating around waiting to be logged or by some other means obtained.