# Alternative to hard coded password

Tags: java, passwords, bing-api, hardcoded

I am writing a java program that uses the Bing Api. I recently decided to open source my code at [code.google.com](http://code.google.com). However, I am looking for an alternative to hardcoding the key. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the password from a file, and don't upload the file to the repository.

Answer (score 2):

Store the password as a hash in a file. Then read it from the file. You can use any already built hashing that you like.

This SO question has awesome info on how you can start hashing today: [How can I hash a password in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860943/suggestions-for-library-to-hash-passwords-in-java)

Also no need to save the file to the project, just make the path to your Desktop, for example.

Comment: Ok, now I have the hash and salt, what steps do I need to decode it in the program?

Comment: The user does not input the password. What i need to encode is a API key to send.

Comment: I think I'll use this tomorrow.http://blog.sortedset.com/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-a-password-stored-in-a-properties-file-with-java-jasypt-apache-commons-configuration/

Comment: Looks good, it has nice tester code.