# Fill a JPasswordField programmatically without creating a String object

Tags: java, swing, jpasswordfield

Is there a simple way to fill the document of a `JPasswordField` without creating a String object that contains the password?

I was trying to create a "change password" dialog which takes in the old password and requires the new one to be entered twice (three password fields), where the old password may be known before hand, depending on how the user configured this (password may have been stored). So instead of requiring the user to enter the existing password each time the associated dialog is shown to her, I wanted to fill it out programmatically.

Note that `JPasswordField.setText(String)` and the `String` constructor are not an option. I'd like to do this using a `char` array.

I've been trying to abuse `GapContent` which seems to be used by `PlainDocument`, but it doesn't seem to work (the chars are in there but the field is corrupted):

```java
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.GapContent;

public class FillJPasswordField extends JFrame {

    private JPasswordField pass;

    public FillJPasswordField() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        char[] password = new char[]{'p', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd'};
        PlainDocument doc = new PlainDocument(new MyGapContent(password));

        pass = new JPasswordField(doc, null, 20);

        // see if the password is in there
        System.out.println(new String(pass.getPassword()));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0d;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 5, 10, 5);

        add(pass, gbc);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new FillJPasswordField().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyGapContent extends GapContent {

        public MyGapContent() {
            super();
        }

        public MyGapContent(int initialLength) {
            super(initialLength);
        }

        public MyGapContent(char[] content) {
            this(content.length);
            replace(0, 0, content, content.length);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you fill the `old-password` field with as many asterisks (*) as the old password has ? You can store the amount in an int, without storing the actual password. Also, if you're storing a password make sure you hash it first. (For help on hashing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860943/suggestions-for-library-to-hash-passwords-in-java)

Comment: @Charlie, I can fake it, but would like to know if filling it with the actual value is possible.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but can't you make a `String` from a `char[]` using `new String(char[])` and use that?

Comment: @Charlie, as stated in the question, I'd like to avoid doing that. For the same reasons as `JPasswordField` implementation itself.

Comment: Even if technically possible, e.g. via reflection, you'd lose the security benefit of always requiring the old password; handle forgotten a password separately.

Comment: @trashgod, this is not a case of "forgotten password". My app can store credentials on behalf of the user using two way encryption.

Comment: I'd still ask as a way to reject a hijacked session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.. The following seems to work:

```java
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.GapContent;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

public class FillJPasswordField extends JFrame {

    private JPasswordField pass;

    public FillJPasswordField() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        char[] password = new char[]{'p', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd'};

        MyGapContent content = new MyGapContent();
        PlainDocument doc = new PlainDocument(content);
        try {
            content.insertChars(0, password);
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
        }
        pass = new JPasswordField(20);
        pass.setDocument(doc);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0d;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 5, 10, 5);
        add(pass, gbc);

        System.out.println(new String(pass.getPassword()));

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new FillJPasswordField().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyGapContent extends GapContent {

        public MyGapContent() {
            super();
        }

        public MyGapContent(int initialLength) {
            super(initialLength);
        }

        public void insertChars(int where, char[] chars) throws BadLocationException {
            if (where > length() || where < 0) {
                throw new BadLocationException("Invalid insert", length());
            }
            replace(where, 0, chars, chars.length);
        }
    }
}
```

Previous code didn't seem to like the fact that I was calling `replace` inside the constructor of `MyGapContent`. Perhaps it requires operations to be done in some sequence.

Comment: `public MyGapContent(int initialLength) { super(initialLength); }` isn't necessary here. (Using JavaSE-1.7)

Comment: That's just for the sake of completeness.