# How to set value to a JPassword field?

Tags: java, jpasswordfield

I need to populate `JPassword` field. However it looks like there is no method `setPassword (char [])`

The only method for this is to `setText` . However I will need to feed a `String`

Since `getText` is deprecated , so I presume `setText` will also be deprecated.

Here is an extract from an [answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443308/why-gettext-in-jpasswordfield-was-deprecated)

`When calling getText you get a String (immutable object) that may not be changed (except reflection) and so the password stays in the memory until garbage collected`

So does the same thing happen when I `setText` . I feed a `String` and it stays in memory. Why isn't `setText` deprecated? Why isn't  there a `setPassword (char [])` method  ?

Comment: Here is an example that uses the field's `PlainDocument` and a char array (that you may want to clear once the document has been populated) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975275/fill-a-jpasswordfield-programmatically-without-creating-a-string-object

Comment: Looks like that could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why isn't there a setPassword (char []) method ?

Whether you insert a String or a char array in the end it's the same.

> ... so I presume setText will also be deprecated.

No it won't. Usually the user will type in a password. And if you store your passwords somewhere they need to be decrypted and inserted in this field before you can send them.

Comment: Thank you very much. I keep password in `byte []` in the database. Then I convert it to `char []`.  I was expecting to have a method `setPassword (char [])` to render password to `JPasswordField` . However, it looks like I will need to convert `byte []` to `String` as follows `new String (bytePassword, "UTF-8")` and then feed it to `JPasswordField` . This will create a password `String` in the memory , which could be accidentally flushed to console unless it's picked up by the garbage collector

Comment: As john said, being forced to specify the password as a `String` kinda defeats the purpose, and IMO `setText` should be deprecated. Why depend on the security of using a `char[]` if you have to create a `String` containing the password anyways?