# Multiple stage password encryption for Java point of sale system

Tags: java, security, encryption, message-digest

I started using MD5 for password encryption but I realized that once the database has been compromised, passwords can be easily decrypted using a dozen different tools.

I was wondering if it would be practical to make a password encryption implementation that would have different stages.

For example I enter a password like "123" then it gets converted like this:
MD5 then passed on SHA encryption then another MessageDigest. So on and so on. WOuld this increase the security of the passwords from being decrypted? This is for the security guys out there.

Comment: This question has been asked many times in different variants. An excellent answer is [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords)

Comment: Much appreciated, James. I've stumbled across similar questions but not the one you commented here. Excellent answer indeed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I hash a password in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860943/how-can-i-hash-a-password-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

First, MD5 is not recommended for password hashing since it is no longer considered as safe. Try to use SHA-512 and use a salt to increase security. A salt is random data that is used as an additional input to a one-way function that hashes a password or passphrase. 
When you use SHA-512 without salt, you always will have the same output for the same input.

Comment: That's the problem. What I do is store the generated hash in the database. So how would I compare or test the values from the user input and the stored value if they're equal or not? My question was if it would be more secure if I pass it through different message digests or there would be no impact if I do that.

Comment: As I mentioned above, you just store salt next to your hash and whenever a user provided something in your password field, you just take it and hash it along with the salt you already stored and compare the result with the hash value you are storing in database. Doing the same hash operation over and over might add more security but it is also an expensive operation for your CPU. And besides, once the attacker finds a way how are you hashing, he can re-produce it. So, the point of the salt is simply to make it so that one rainbow table can't break every password in the database.

Comment: bcrypt, scrypt ... this problem's been solved, but this answer doesn't mention them.