# SHA512 hashing gives incorrect (?) results when "salted"

Tags: java, hash, salt, sha

I want to implement SHA512 hashing using a salt. I started [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085493/hash-a-password-with-sha-512-in-java), leading to this mcve:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Sha512Mcve {

    private final String ENCODING = "ISO-8859-1";

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(computeHashFor("whatever"));
    }

    private String computeHashFor(String toHash) {
        String salt = "salt";
        MessageDigest md;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
//          md.update(salt.getBytes(ENCODING));
            byte[] bytes = md.digest(toHash.getBytes(ENCODING));

            return toUnixRepresentation(salt, bytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private String toUnixRepresentation(String salt, byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("$6$");
        sb.append(salt);
        sb.append("$");

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            int c = bytes[i] & 0xFF;
            if (c < 16) sb.append("0");
            sb.append(Integer.toHexString(c));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Thing is: when I leave the line `md.update()` commented out, this code gives me the exact **same** results as some *online hash generators* (like this [one](http://www.convertstring.com/Hash/SHA512)).

For example, hashing the word "whatever" gives a hash value ae3d....63a.

But when I run my code with that salt operation; I get **different** results (again compared against that online tool, which allows to set a salt string, too).

My implementation results in 413...623; the online tool says F25...686.

Any explanation in which way "salting" leads to "implementation specific" results?

Is there something I should do differently in my code?

Comment: If you are looking for the password hash, then the hashing method is not just simply using one round of hashing. Please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28C%29  Also if you wish, i have a working Java implementation for this hasing for sha256 and sha512 ( written from scratch )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salt before or after?

What the calculator does when you set the salt option

> whateversalt

What you are doing in your code

> saltwhatever

resutls from the calculator

whateversalt

```
F2527142C752B05467EE53B44735397F5B4C870DF0F154A0CF3AC23B31CF42EE7E1002D326B57DF60ED4B7449CF101290BDC0BECCB677AAAD846CFBE140DF686
```

saltwhatever

```
41333B9BAFC14CB3D1106D72A5D461F348B9EA1304A82989E00E5FC2D3239339492FCA12ED5EBF5F6802955C95B5F7ADA4CA035A911C2F29ABE905C3923CF623
```

Therefore to match the calculation you just have to reverse the order and add the salt last

```
        md.update(toHash.getBytes(ENCODING));
        byte[] bytes = md.digest(salt.getBytes(ENCODING));
```

Or even

```
        md.update(toHash.getBytes(ENCODING));
        md.update(salt.getBytes(ENCODING));
        byte[] bytes = md.digest();
```