# SHA-512 hashing with Android

Tags: java, hash, sha512

I was wondering if I can SHA-512 hash a string on Android Studio **without a salt**.

I've seen other questions, but they all involve the `salt`, but I want something like this:

```
TestBox.text = sha512("Hello, world!");
```

And `TextBox` will read `c1527cd893c124773d811911970c8fe6e857d6df5dc9226bd8a160614c0cd963a4ddea2b94bb7d36021ef9d865d5cea294a82dd49a0bb269f51f6e7a57f79421`;

Comment: This is not an Android-specific question, and can be tackled using standard Java libraries.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The other questions you saw use salt so just don't use salt like so:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
byte[] digest = md.digest("Hello, world!".getBytes());
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
    sb.append(Integer.toString((digest[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33085670/1398418).

Answer (score 6):

Keds example is right, but .length will always be biger than 32, (127) so more correct answer should be

```
private fun getSHA512(input:String):String{
    val md: MessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512")
    val messageDigest = md.digest(input.toByteArray())

    // Convert byte array into signum representation
    val no = BigInteger(1, messageDigest)

    // Convert message digest into hex value
    var hashtext: String = no.toString(16)

    // Add preceding 0s to make it 128 chars long
    while (hashtext.length < 128) {
        hashtext = "0$hashtext"
    }



    // return the HashText
    return hashtext
}
```

Answer (score 2):

method for calculating sha-512 in kotlin

```
 fun getSHA256(input:String):String{
    return MessageDigest
        .getInstance("SHA-256")
        .digest(input.toByteArray())
        .fold("") { str, it -> str + "%02x".format(it) }
}
```

Comment: Here the length of has txt should be 128 so if less than that is found then needs to insert the '0' at the starting of the string 
Please Edit this.
// Add preceding 0s to make it 128 chars long
    while (hashtext.length < 128) {
        hashtext = "0$hashtext"
    }

Answer (score 0):

A more functional solution:

```kotlin
fun sha512(input: String): String {
        return MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512")
            .digest(input.toByteArray())
            .joinToString(separator = "") {
                ((it.toInt() and 0xff) + 0x100)
                    .toString(16)
                    .substring(1) 
            }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I guess the equivalent in Kotlin is:

```
fun encriptar(cadena: String): String {

    var md: MessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512")
    var digest = md.digest(cadena.toByteArray())
    var sb: StringBuilder = StringBuilder()

    var i = 0
    while (i < digest.count()) {
        sb.append(((digest[i] and 0xff.toByte()) + 0x100).toString(16).substring(0, 1))
        i++
    }

    return sb.toString()
}
```