# How to hash a password with SHA2-512 in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, sql-server-2008, sha2

I have SHA2-512 password encryption set up on my application. While creating users, the password is created using the below method:

```
DECLARE @salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER=NEWID(); select
HASHBYTES('SHA2_512','password'+CAST(@salt AS NVARCHAR(36)))
```

I am now trying to implement this in Java. I see the `MessageDigest` helps creating `SHA-512` but `SHA2-512` throws `NoSuchAlgorithmException` exception.

Any suggestions with appropriate methods of getting this on Java side will be helpful.

Comment: Are you saying that you copy-pasted a solution from [a question like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085493/how-to-hash-a-password-with-sha-512-in-java), ran it, and found that SHA-512 is not available?

Comment: I didn't copy paste a solution, but I did copy-paste a question with a different algorithm. Anything wrong in doing that when it just means what I want it to mean?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. You can just use `SHA-512`, since this is the canonical name for the same algorithm. SHA-512 is from the SHA2 series of hashes, and there's no 512 bit version of SHA1. (PS: this is not a secure way to store passwords)