# My change password interface is not working on java eclipse web application

Tags: java, database, servlets

I've created this change password interface, but for some reason it doesn't seem to be updating the password in the database, which means something is wrong with my code. Could someone please take a look, thanks! The problem is not comparing strings, as I have corrected that and it is still not working, so can I please have this question reopened, thanks :)

ChangePassword.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset = "UTF-8"> 
<title>Change Password</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action ="NewPassword" method = post> 
    <h1>Change Password</h1>
    <b>Enter Old Password:</b>
    <br>
    <input type = "password" name = "oldpassword" size = "20"> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <b>Enter New Password:</b>
    <br>
    <input type = "password" name = "newpassword" size = "20"> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <b>Confirm New Password</b>
    <br>
    <input type = "password" name = "confirmpassword" size = "20"> 
    <br> 
    <br>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Update Password">
    <br>
    <br>
    </form>.
</body>

</html>
```

NewPassword.java

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class NewPassword extends HttpServlet { 
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

                response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

                String oldpassword = request.getParameter("oldpassword"); 
                String newpassword = request.getParameter("newpassword"); 
                String confirmpassword = request.getParameter("confirmpassword"); 

                HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
                String employeeid = ""; 

                if(session != null) { 
                    employeeid = (String)session.getAttribute("employeeid"); 
                }

                boolean st = false; 
                try { 
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payroll_system", "root", ""); 
                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT pwd FROM payroll_system.employee_login WHERE employeeID = ?");
                    ps.setString(1, employeeid);
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(); 
                    st = rs.next(); 
                    if(st) { 

                        String currentpassword = rs.getString("pwd"); 
                        if((currentpassword.equals(oldpassword)) && newpassword.equals(confirmpassword)) { 
                            PreparedStatement pd = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE payroll_system.employee_login SET pwd = ? where employeeID = ?" ); 
                            pd.setString(1, newpassword);
                            pd.setString(2, employeeid);
                            ResultSet rd = pd.executeQuery(); 
                            st = rd.next(); 
                            if(st) { 
                                out.println("successfully updated password");
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }catch(Exception e)
                 {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
               out.close();
       }
   }
```

Comment: @StefanBeike Oh, maybe that's why haha. Sorry, I've only been using select statements so far.

Comment: @StefanBeike Could you please guide me? where to put the commit and how

Comment: voted to reopen because of the main problem was executing the query. compare strings was just a part of the problem.

Comment: As an aside, you probably shouldn't be storing those passwords in plain text in the database.  Use a one-way hash like SHA-256 instead.

Comment: @daiscog How exactly would I implement this in mysql? And how do you know I'm storing it as plain text?

Comment: @Programmer I can see it's being stored as plain text because your code compares the passwords without hashing and just inserts the passwords straight into the database.  Unless you've deliberately missed out the hashing part of your code in your post for brevity, then you're storing them in plain text.  For info and an example of hashing see [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Hashing_Java#Complete_Java_Sample), [here](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#javasourcecode) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860943/how-can-i-hash-a-password-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats wrong:

```
if(passmatch == oldpassword && newpassword == confirmpassword) {
```

use `equals` to compare `Strings`:

```
if(passmatch.equals(oldpassword) && newpassword.equals(confirmpassword)) {
```

with `==` you compare the object references and not the values.

Furthermore change `ResultSet rd = pd.executeQuery();` to `int updated = pd.executeUpdate();` and change the if to `if (updated>0)`

Comment: This checks to make sure that the update is only done when old password = current password and new password = confirm password

Comment: Oh I see, thanks, do I still have to commit though? Is the issue the commit or the == statement? or both?

Comment: yes but you want to compare the values and not the references. the commit is only necessary if autocommit is not true in your connection.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll try that out and give you your tick :)

Comment: any error or message?

Comment: Nop, none. It doesn't even print 'successfully updated password'

Comment: is your servlet called successfully?

Comment: Yep, it is, since I'm not getting any http error

Comment: And now my question is getting duplicated for 'comparing string', even though that's not the issue...and a downvote.

Comment: what happens if you change ResultSet rd = pd.executeQuery(); to int updated = pd.executeUpdate();

Comment: Then what about the st = rd.next();

Comment: change the if to if (updated>0)

Comment: glad to help you. feel free to accept my answer.