# Insert password via Java application to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I try to insert information from a Java application to a database in mySQL. It only works if I remove the password part. It gives me a warning when I put in the values that say (regarding the passwordField.getPassword()): "`Must explicitly convert the char[] to a 
 String`" <- What does this mean?

See code below

```
JButton btnSkapaInlogg = new JButton("Skapa inlogg");
btnSkapaInlogg.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try{
            theQuery("insert into kund " +
                "(user_name, password, first_name, last_name, mobil, email, adress, ort) " + 
                "values('"+textField.getText()+"','"+passwordField.getPassword()+"',
                '"+textField_3.getText()+"','"+textField_4.getText()+"','"+textField_5.getText()+"',
                '"+textField_6.getText()+"','"+textField_7.getText()+"','"+textField_8.getText()+"',
                '"+textField_9.getText()+"')");
        }
          catch(Exception ex){}
        }
});
```

Comment: The error message tell you whats wrong. Post a [mcve] to get help sooner

Comment: **WARNING**: This is full of [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). You **must** [properly escape all values](http://bobby-tables.com/java.html). If possible, use prepared statements with placeholder values.

Answer (score 1):

> Must explicitly convert the char[] to a String
>
> What does this mean?

It means that `passwordField.getPassword()` returns an array of `char` while a `String` is expected.

The easiest way to convert an array of `char` to a `String` is [`new String(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-char:A-) but **it is not how you are supposed to store a password in your database** anyway, you are supposed to hash it first (ideally with salt) otherwise it will be a clear `String` in your database which is a **security hole**.

For more info about how to hash a password, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860943/how-can-i-hash-a-password-in-java).

The second mistake is the fact that **your query is not correct**, you provide **9 values** while you define **only 8 fields**, so you need to add the missing field to fix your query first.

Comment: Nicolas is correct. In a production environment, the password itself should be encrypted then stored in the database.  That way, if anyone should get hold of the database records, they won't be able to discern the meaning of the passwords, also as the encrypted form of the password is transmitted over the internet, it will not be readable.

Answer (score -1):

You have 8 columns but your data is 9 columns

```
(user_name, password, first_name, last_name, mobil, email, adress, ort)

values('"+textField.getText()+"','"+passwordField.getPassword()+"','"+textField_3.getText()+"','"+textField_4.getText()+"','"+textField_5.getText()+"','"+textField_6.getText()+"','"+textField_7.getText()+"','"+textField_8.getText()+"','"+textField_9.getText()+"')")
```

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson. While technically correct, the answer is prone to SQL injection, doesn't mention the dangers of saving plain passwords in a database.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use char array as a string,

```
passwordField.getPassword()
```

Returns char array not a string. So before you concatenate it with a string you have to convert it to a string.

Here is a code to build string from a char array.

```
String pw=new String(passwordField.getPassword())
```

Use pw variable in your query instead of directly calling passwordField.getPassword()

Here is updated code

```
String pw=new String(passwordField.getPassword());
JButton btnSkapaInlogg = new JButton("Skapa inlogg");
btnSkapaInlogg.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try{
        theQuery("insert into kund " +
            "(user_name, password, first_name, last_name, mobil, email, adress, ort) " + 
            "values('"+textField.getText()+"','"+pw+"',
            '"+textField_3.getText()+"','"+textField_4.getText()+"','"+textField_5.getText()+"',
            '"+textField_6.getText()+"','"+textField_7.getText()+"','"+textField_8.getText()+"',
            '"+textField_9.getText()+"')");
    }
      catch(Exception ex){}
    }
});
```

**Update :** You have to encrypt the passwords before storing in in the DB, it is not a good idea to store it as a plain text

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson. While technically correct, the answer is prone to SQL injection, doesn't mention the dangers of saving plain passwords in a database.