# hybris: Import encoded password through impex

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

In Hybris 6 -
How can we import encoded password from csv file to our database through impex by using password encoder: pbkdf2 so that password will store in database as same as in impex. But we can login into site with normal password?

I have tried to put hash value in impex and written `;@password[translator=de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.translators.UserPasswordTranslator]` as attribute in impex. When I have tried to login with normal password, it is giving number format exception with encoded value.

Please help me, how can I import encoded password?

Comment: Do passwords come from an existing hybris installation?

Comment: Password will come through csv file ,which we are importing.Password is already in encoded format in csv file

Answer (score 0):

I guess the correct way to import encoded password would be :

```
insert_update Employee;encodedPassword;passwordEncoding;
;<your_encoded hash>;pbkdf2
```

But I fear you'll have trouble to authenticate if the provider of the password is different from the entity that will check passwords.

You can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2861125/1140748) where you can find a PBKDF2 implementation in Java. Maybe you'll have to customize hybris behaviour to validate your passwords.