# Hashing passwords in Java servlet

Tags: java, hash, passwords

I earlier found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2861125/5591259) answer regarding hashing passwords in Java, but I'm using Java 7 while the answer works only in Java 8.
I tried to adapt it without success, so... Any suggestions?
I also downloaded the bouncycastle library, but I don't understand how it works...

Thank you for your time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I hash a password in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860943/how-can-i-hash-a-password-in-java)

Comment: I have already seen it, but I am unsure about how I can use the code posted there in Java 7... @Ravi

Comment: Looked through the code of the linked question. I didn't find any Java 8 specific syntax. I think you can use these methods with some caution in respect to the availablility of some crypto algos.

Comment: It is clearly mentioned in accepted answer **The SunJCE in Java 6 supports PBKDF2, which is a good algorithm to use for password hashing**

Comment: @blafasel java.util.Base64 is not recognized...

Comment: @Ravi PBKDF2 is not recognised... And importing com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE doesn't work, because it doesn't exist

Comment: Take [Apache commons Base64](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html). Or take the Sun implementation (`sun.misc.somewhat`). And get your JCE problems fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) it very simple to use.

**For** **example**:

```
private static final String ENC_ALGORITHM = "PBEWithMD5AndDES";
...
StandardPBEStringEncryptor textEncryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
textEncryptor.setAlgorithm(ENC_ALGORITHM);
textEncryptor.setPassword("MySuperSecretSeed"); // make sure this is stored somewhere safe like an ENV variable
String encryptedPassword = textEncryptor.encrypt("Password to be encrypted");
```