# Java Databases: PreparedStatement setBytes vs setBinaryStream for hashed password

Tags: java, arrays, database, hash, passwords

I want to store an hashed 64 bytes password contained inside a BigInteger into an SQL database.

Which of these metohods should I use? Does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what you are trying to do, but if I understood correctly you want to hash the PW form the DB and store it locally.
This is what I have used before, and considering the @erickson explained it pretty clearly just give it a peak if [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860943/how-can-i-hash-a-password-in-java) is what you are trying to do.
Good luck :)

Comment: Edited my question, it probably was a bit ambiguous. Anyway I already managed to hash and store the password inside a BigInteger (and gave it a 64 bytes size); now I want to store it in an SQL Database

Comment: Didn't see the title -> setBinaryStream will use memory buffering to read the stream and send a block at a time to the server and this can be useful if the data is really big, but in your case I would go with setBytes because you are already have all the 64 bytes of data in your memory, just push it.