# Can CrudRepository retrieve data by attributes?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How can I develop a method generic to retrieve data by attribute. Let's say we have a User Class

```
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String username;
private String password;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

}
```

UserRepository

```
public interface  UserRepository  extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    
    Optional<User> findOneByUsername(String username);
    Optional<User> findUsersByAttributes(String attribute);
    
}
```

I want to develop a method to retrieve data by attribute :

```
findUsersByAttributes(String attribute){

}
```

Comment: Try QueryDsl or Specification class

Comment: This should not be possible, but if you have few attributes you can write a method for each of them. If you need to combine multiple attributes like `findAllByFirstNameAndLastnameAndMoreAttributes` then above comment is a better solution, as the amount of options would grow too fast.

Comment: @Glains @pvpkiran can explain more or example : what i expected it's when user send like :
`*/user?lastname=Johon // retrive data for Johon`
`*/user?userName=Red   // retrive data for Red`
So the filter based parameter

Comment: @user4343 See my anser below. I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

### Entity

You already provided your entity, but i added the missing annotations so it can be picked up by any jpa implementation. Just a quick reminder here, whenever you store a password you should consider hashing passwords and not store them as plaintext in your database. You can find more information about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860943/how-can-i-hash-a-password-in-java?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    // remainer ommitted for brevity
}
```

### Repository

The most simple option is to create methods using Spring Data JPA.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    Optional<User> findOneByUsername(String username);
    List<User> findAllByFirstName(String firstName);
    List<User> findAllByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

However, consider the case where you might want to query users for more attributes at the same time. For example, if you want to find a user by `firstName`, `lastName`, `gender`, `phoneNumber`, ... it would be impossible to write methods for all sorts of combinations.

```
findAllByFirstNameAndLastNameAndGenderAndPhoneNumber // pretty confusing
```

If you only need a few properties, you can use `CrudRepository` as stated above, if you need more properties you might want to have a look at *QueryDSL* or *Specifications*, which deal exactly with that problem. More information about this [here](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/).

### Service

Next up, you should create a service to decouple your data layer.

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    private UserRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    Optional<User> findOneByUsername(String username) {
        return repository.findOneByUsername(username);
    }

    List<User> findAllByFirstName(String firstName) {
        return repository.findAllByFirstName(firstName);
    }

    List<User> findAllByLastName(String lastName) {
       return repository.findAllByLastName(lastName);
    }
}
```

### Controller

Finally, create a controller to access you service layer.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public UserController {

    private UserService service;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping()
    @ResponseBody
    public List<User> findAll(@RequestParam(value = "username", required = false) String username, 
          @RequestParam(value = "firstName", required = false) String firstName, 
          @RequestParam(value = "lastName", required = false) String lastName) {
        if (username != null) {
            return List.of(service.findOneByUsername(username));
        }
        if (firstName != null) {
            return service.findAllByFirstName(username);
        }
        if (lastName!= null) {
            return service.findAllByLastName(username);
        }
        return service.findAll();
    }
}
```

One last note here, think about whether you want to make you password field also available in requests, if not i would recommend using a UserDTO and [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/).