# Can CBC mode be used for saving passwords in a program for customers?

Tags: c++, cryptography, passwords, password-protection, crypto++

It is new for me to work with the Crypto++ library and I'm not going to understand why they say CBC-Mode is usually not enough to protect/secure my data.

So can I deal with the CBC-Mode if I would like to use it with user passwords or not?

---

***EDIT*** (from the comments):

I would like to create a program that encrypt strings with the Crypto++ library. I would like to transform data in order to keep it secret, like user passwords from a program/website, I mean like a password saver/container, with AES.

Comment: You should take a look at [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2), which was specially designed to hash passwords and won the PHC 2015 competition. Its reference implementation is in [C / C++](https://github.com/p-h-c/phc-winner-argon2)

Comment: CBC is not the way to go. As a programmer, don't invent new methods like how to hash passwords, use tested tried and true methods instead, designed by people, who work in the field.

Comment: Frist, thanks for the fast answer. Okay thanks.

Comment: Also, this might not be great advice, but personally, I stopped trying to understand everything cryptographers reason/do. *Over there* things get complicated and messy quickly and you can easily break things by implementing secure algorithms in a wrong way. Just trust your friends over at https://security.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: Haha okay :) I think your right, i watched the opensource code from the cryptopp lib....thats really 'stackoverflow'. I will looking for some nice advise and informations about a 'good' lib to use in my programm :) The page is great, i never hearded about that before.

Comment: I would like to create a programm that encrypt strings with the Crypto++ library. I would like to transform data in order to keep it secret, like user passwords from a programm/website, I mean like a password saver/container, with AES.

Comment: Without the full requirements I doubt anyone is going to be able to help you. If you are encrypting strings, then you should consider either (1) block cipher operated with an [authenticated encryption](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_Encryption) mode; (2) stream cipher with authentication tag, like [ChaChaPoly1305](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ChaCha20Poly1305); or (3) [ECIES](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) or other integrated encryption scheme.

Comment: ECIES (3) is most likely a better choice because it is [IND-CCA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability#IND-CCA2), which is a strong notion of security. IND-CCA2 means an attacker cannot distinguish ciphertext from random with more than negligible probability. And since ECIES is an integrated scheme the attacker won't find oracles to help guess at the strings.

Comment: Please see this [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I hash a password in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860943/how-can-i-hash-a-password-in-java)

Comment: Don't use CBC mode for anything. If you need to encrypt, use an AEAD mode. But [passwords need special handling, not encryption](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords).