# Change a line to prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO LOGIN VALUES(" + jTextField1.getText() + ",'" + jTextField2.getText() + "'," + jTextField3.getText() + ")");
```

I have this line and I am trying to do this line prepared statement but I am not able to do it.
What I did is this :

```
   PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE Login
                                     SET login_id = ? WHERE username = ?");
```

the sql table is this

```
CREATE TABLE login(
  login_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  password varchar(150) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Did you set the parameter values? Generally you dont change the primary key after insertion. Post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This folwoing code should be encapsuled in a ty catch statment

Also i hope you add a [password hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860943/how-can-i-hash-a-password-in-java) function to your code, every thing else is very insecure.

```
  PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO LOGIN VALUES (?,?,?)");
  pstmt.setInt    (1, Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()));
  pstmt.setString (2, jTextField2.getText());
  pstmt.setString (3, jTextField2.getText()));


  // execute the preparedstatement
  pstmt.execute();
```

Comment: thank you a lot man I appreciated

Answer (score 0):

observed parameterized object to avoid SQL Injections. just a bunch of security. although that one, you have provided is Okay for learning purposes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).